# How to see if one variable is greater to another

Tags: java, compare

I want to find out if 1 variable is greater then another. I am trying to compare two strings to see which card is higher then the other but I am very new at coding and do not know how to do this. I think it would go something like this

```
 if ( cardName1 > cardName2 && cardName1 > cardName3){
        System.out.println( cardName1 + " high");
    }
```

but obviously this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use String.compareTo which will compare two Strings lexicographically

For example

```
if (cardName1.compareTo (cardName2) > 0) {
   System.out.println ("cardName1 is greater");
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Comment: Be care what you name the cards. Lexicographical order may not be value order.

Comment: @AlexA would you like to explain more what you mean?

Comment: suppose you are playing a game with three cards that are named, `king`, `queen`, and `jack`, then lexicographical order is: `king` > `jack` > `queen`; however, the value in a game may be `king` > `queen` > `jack`. Your answer is correct, but the names must reflect the relative value of their card.

Comment: @AlexA Thanks, sorry I was not even thinking along the lines of normal playing cards.  The OP should take this into consideration